# Go: why does time.Now().Hour/Minute/Second return a six digit number?

Tags: time, go

I am learning how to code in Go and trying to create a simple reminder function.

I want to display the current time as a regular 24 hour clock, XX.XX (hours, minutes).

I have saved the current time in a variable t and when I print it I find out that the time is 23.00 early November 2009. Fine, but when I print t.Hour and t.Minute the result is `132288.132480`.

It is something similar when I print `t.Seconds`. I have not been able to figure out why this happens.

Roughly 2000 days have passed since but that is only 48k hours and 2880k minutes so the small difference between the hours and minutes in my result hints that the issue is something else.

I am running the code in the go playground.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    )

func main() {
    Remind("It's time to eat")
}


func Remind(text string) {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Printf("The time is %d.%d: ", t.Hour, t.Minute)
    fmt.Printf(text)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Comment: `Hour` and `Minute` are functions; you need to evaluate them: `fmt.Printf("The time is %d.%d: ", t.Hour(), t.Minute())`.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that was simple and obvious. Thanks! 

Do you know then what t.Hour actually returns? And why is it so similar to t.Minute and t.Second?

Comment: t.Hour and t.Minutes are references to the functions, not the result of the functions. You can think of them as addresses in memory where these functions are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `t.Hour()` instead of using it as a value.

Check out the source of `time` package here: https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=12994:13018#L390

```
   399  // Hour returns the hour within the day specified by t, in the range [0, 23].
   400  func (t Time) Hour() int {
   401      return int(t.abs()%secondsPerDay) / secondsPerHour
   402  }
   403
```

When in doubt, you can quickly find an explanation by reading specific package source from official [go packages page](https://golang.org/pkg/).

Comment: Well, I had read the time package page, but I didn't realise I wasn't calling hour in the correct way as a function. Do you know what `t.Hour` returns?